# Arduino with L298N Motor Driver and external Power

Tags: safety, mains, ground-loop

I would like to control a slave clock which requires 24v applied for approx 1/2 second in alternating directions once every minute and have bought a Arduino Uno to control the pulses.  The Arduino is synchronised to radio time via a DCF77 module.

[image]

In order to drive the clock (which is an inductive load) I propose to use a L298N module as this has an H-bridge to easily reverse the polarity of the pulses.

[image]

So far so good.

I have bought myself a cheap 24v power supply and when manually directly connecting the power one way and then the other to the clock the minute hand advances correctly.

My question relates to wiring these three components together whilst at the same time developing the required software from my PC.

The UNO is powered from the USB port of my PC, which is also used for serial communication during programming and serial I/O during operation of my sketch.

The L298N will additionally require power from the 24v adapter.

In order for the circuit to operate I understand that I will need a common ground between the Arduino and the L298N.  This seems to imply that I need a common ground between my 24v cheap adapter and the ground side of the USB coming out of my PC.

Is this a safe configuration?  Or is there a worry that the ground side the my PC's USB port and the outer sleeve of the 24v power supply are at different potential and that this is dangerous?

Advice appreciated before I plug it in!  Thanks!

Comment: Does it have a ground connection on mains?

Comment: The 24v wall wart supply has three pins (as we do as standard in the UK) but I notice that the Earth pin is made of plastic so that supply only has Live and Neutral connections.  The PC power cable has a three pin connector with Live, Neutral and Earth which then attaches to the PC Switched power supply and later onward to the motherboard etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in identifying that a ground loop like this is a potential safety issue. The way to avoid it is to either make sure that both grounds are at the same potential, or to isolate the ground points, whether in one or both of the power supplies or in the intermediate connection itself.

Measuring the ground potential difference is not difficult, but has its own safety issues. If measuring two mains ground potentials at the outlets, a [CAT II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_category) or better digital multimeter with at least 600V of protection should be used. The measurement taken between the two ground points must be either 0V (same potential) or floating (isolated), and both AC and DC voltages should be checked.

To verify if a three-pronged power supply is isolated, measure the resistance between the power supply return and the mains ground pin. If it is less than about 100ohms after a few seconds then the supply is non-isolated. This is of course not necessarily a problem in and of itself, only when you combine it with other non-isolated devices at a different ground potential.

Comment: I noted that my multimeter had a Cat II label so I put one lead on the ground of the Arduino and attached the other to the centre of the output of the 24v wall wart.  On DC there is negligible reading however when switching to AC I get a reading of 83.7v, if I try the outer part of the output plug I likewise get a reading of 83.7v.

Comment: That 83.7V is just capacitive coupling to a floating 24V supply. Measure the current from that supply to a good ground (or your USB Arduino's ground) and it'll be in the microamps. Then connecting the common ground will be safe.